# Why does the structure of HTML page is changes, after what I try display some table from DB with PHP?

Tags: php, html, database

Initial I have this structure of Html page what is separated in 2 part,
1-st with content and 2nd contains footer:

```
<html>
   <head> 
     .... 
   </head>
   <body>
      <div class="content">

          <!-- Here is a form what help user to search some table from DB -->
          <?php include_once "search\search_form.php" ?>

          <!-- This div is the place where will be print the table -->
             <div class='right-side'>
                <!-- Here I print the searched table from DB -->
                <?php include_once "search\search_on.php" ?>
             </div>

      </div>
      <footer>
          ....
      </footer>
   </body>
</html>
```

After what the table is shown I get automatically this structure:

```
<html>
   <head> 
     .... 
   </head>
   <body>
      <div class="content">

          <!-- Here is a form what help user to search some table from DB -->
          <?php include_once "search\search_form.php" ?>

          <!-- This div is the place where will be print the table -->
             <div class='right-side'>

                <footer>
                   ....
                </footer>

                <!-- Here I print the searched table from DB -->
                <table>
                   .....
                </table>
             </div>

      </div>
   </body>
</html>
```

If you can see, footer has moved inside the DIV where class="right-side"
WHY ???

Comment: show us the html printed by search\search_on.php all by itself. I suspect you have malformed HTML, with div tags without matching closing tag. Browser is adding the closing tags at the end.

Comment: Inside search\search_form.php  I don't have any DIV

Comment: Check in search_on.php as well. I agree with @NawedKhan, PHP isn't going to add a random div to your HTML like that. Check the raw page source instead of viewing the processed HTML in a browser inspect tool and you should see the code you expect.

Comment: I actually see this structure with browser inspect tool. Where is the same that I explain you

Comment: I forgot to close the <table> TAG :), now it works well

Comment: Yeah, I meant _don't_ use the inspect tool. Inspect will show you the HTML after the browser did it's best to fix any problems with the markup. View Page Source will show you the HTML you actually sent.